# Dell XPS m1530 system cannot boot need 130w or greater

Tags: battery, dell-xps

I have a Dell XPS M1530 and I lost my old AC adapter but ordered a new one. For the longest time it always had a battery charge so I was able to boot into the OS but now it is completely dead. I have a generic charger that slowly charged the laptop when it was in the OS but does not when the computer is off.

When I boot up I get the following error:

```
The AC power adapter type cannot be determined. The system can only boot with a 130 W power adapter or greater.
Strike F1 key to shutdown.
```

I cannot even enter the BIOs setup screen or boot menu, is there a way around this? I heard from the local tech that Dell has a special feature to boot from thumb drive before getting past the initial logo.

I am doing my best to avoid purchasing a new charger since it worked just fine when the OS was running, I am hoping to get this thing going. Is there a way to charge the battery externally? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

They make external battery chargers, but they cost as much an AC adapter.

[image]

IMO, get the proper AC adapter and be done with it. The work around you seek might be more trouble than its worth.

Comment: So I bought a replacement adapter which is the PA-4E and it still prompts for correct wattage!! This is driving me insane, now I bought a replacement DC jack and will desolder/solder in this one. Hopefully this corrects the issue.